# How do I position the quote in moderncv below the cv content?

Tags: positioning, moderncv

Is it possible to position the quote below the CV content in moderncv? E.g. in the following MWE I'd like the quote to appear below section "B".

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.20}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\quote{{\raggedright\color{dark-gray}\lipsum[1]}} 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{A}
\cvline{a}{\ldots}
\cvline{b}{\ldots}
\section{B}
\cvline{a}{\ldots}
\cvline{b}{\ldots}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to place the quote at some random point, don't use `\quote` command but define a new one:

```
\newcommand{\putquote}[1]{%
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{#1}\end{minipage}\par}
}%
```

and then use it anywhere you like:

```
\putquote{{\raggedright\color{dark-gray}\lipsum[1]}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.20}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\newcommand{\putquote}[1]{%
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{#1}\end{minipage}\par}
}%

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{A}
\cvline{a}{\ldots}
\cvline{b}{\ldots}
\section{B}
\cvline{a}{\ldots}
\cvline{b}{\ldots}

\putquote{{\raggedright\color{dark-gray}\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that was easy! :) Didn't think of that!